# Animation of menu items in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

When you long click on email item in `Gmail` application (`Honeycomb`) the context-like menu is shown with it's items animated on start. How this is made? Thanks.

Comment: You will get some answers if you just describe the way animation appears. No one will care to go and check the gmail app for honeycomb.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html). You can animate any view calling an animation to start on it.

Comment: Exactly--a view animation doesn't help the least bit, since items in the ActionBar are `MenuItem`s.

Comment: The question is probably about animating MenuItems, not views

Comment: Does not address MenuItems

Comment: This is not relevant to menu items

Answer (score 2):

You cannot animate MenuItems, so the trick is to set a same looking View in its place with MenuItem.setActionView() and animate that view as you would normally and then unset it when animation is done with MenuItem.setActionView(null)

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

   private Menu mOptionsMenu;

   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       mOptionsMenu = menu;
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_main, menu);
   }

   private void animateActionBarItem() {
       final MenuItem refreshItem = mOptionsMenu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
       refreshItem.setActionView(R.layout.actionbar_foo);
       refreshItem.getActionView()
            .animate()
            .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator())
            .setDuration(100L)
            .scaleX(2F)
            .scaleY(2F)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    refreshItem.setActionView(null);
                }
            });
      }

}
```

XML for R.layout.actionbar_foo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043544/animating-action-bar-icons-appearing-on-fragment-changes). It is related to the layout changes of the parent of menu items, but if you look at my idea there, you will catch a glimpse how to animate menu items.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve animation fr the MenuItems is via Animated Vector Drawables,as

1. First create an Animated Vector Drawable using [Shape Shifter](https://shapeshifter.design/)

   ````xml
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"> <aapt:attr
   name="android:drawable">
       <vector
           android:name="vector"
           android:width="1024dp"
           android:height="1024dp"
           android:viewportWidth="1024"
           android:viewportHeight="1024">
           <path
               android:name="path"
               android:pathData="M 289.1 296.7 L 382.1 296.7 C 390.584 296.7 398.729 300.074 404.727 306.073 C 410.726 312.071 414.1 320.216 414.1 328.7 C 414.1 337.184 410.726 345.329 404.727 351.327 C 398.729 357.326 390.584 360.7 382.1 360.7 L 233 360.7 C 224.516
   360.7 216.371 357.326 210.373 351.327 C 204.374 345.329 201 337.184 201 328.7 L 201 179.7 C 201 171.216 204.374 163.071 210.373 157.073
   C 216.371 151.074 224.516 147.7 233 147.7 C 241.484 147.7 249.629
   151.074 255.627 157.073 C 261.626 163.071 265 171.216 265 179.7 L 265 230.3 C 338.599 162.68 435.767 126.396 535.674 129.226 C 635.58
   132.056 730.538 173.783 800.191 245.461 C 869.844 317.139 908.833 413.253 908.8 513.2 C 908.8 614.987 868.329 712.71 796.364 784.694 C 724.4 856.677 626.687 897.173 524.9 897.2 C 423.096 897.2 325.357 856.715 253.371 784.729 C 181.385 712.743 140.9 615.004 140.9 513.2 L 204.9 513.2 C 204.9 598.037 238.637 679.486 298.626 739.474 C
   358.614 799.463 440.063 833.2 524.9 833.2 C 609.737 833.2 691.186 799.463 751.174 739.474 C 811.163 679.486 844.9 598.037 844.9 513.2 C 844.892 448.761 825.42 385.802 789.047 332.61 C 752.673 279.418
   701.067 238.434 641.02 215.05 C 580.973 191.667 515.241 186.958 452.473 201.542 C 389.706 216.127 332.785 249.336 289.2 296.8 Z"
               android:fillColor="#4b4b4b"/>
       </vector> </aapt:attr> <target android:name="path">
       <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
           <objectAnimator
               android:propertyName="fillAlpha"
               android:duration="1000"
               android:valueFrom="1"
               android:valueTo="0"
               android:valueType="floatType"
               android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"/>
       </aapt:attr> </target> </animated-vector> ```
   ````
2. Now add the Animated Vector Drawable as icon for the MenuItem

   ````xml
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <menu
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

       <item
           android:id="@+id/refresh"
           android:icon="@drawable/refresh_fade_out"
           android:title="Refresh"
           app:showAsAction="always" />

       </menu>  ```
   ````
3. Now start or stop the animation of the Animated Vector Drawable by casting the icon of the MenuItem to [Animatable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Animatable) in Java, as

   ```
      MenuItem refresh=menu.findItem(R.id.refresh); 
      Animatable animatable= (Animatable) refresh.getIcon();
      if (animatable!=null)
         animatable.start();
   ```