# Animating action bar icons appearing on fragment changes

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

My current app has fragment and slidingUpCard navigation. Each one of them has a different set of active `ActionBar` elements and the buttons change with the screen. I was wondering if there was a way of animating the buttons coming and going similar to what `android:animateLayoutChanges` would do for a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your question. I'm not sure if it is possible to add `animateLayoutChanges` to the  [ActionBarContainer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/com/android/internal/widget/ActionBarContainer.java#ActionBarContainer) that holds the `ActionBar`. But still you can access the `ActionBarView` in same manner as you will see a bit down in this answer.

Hierarchy: `ActionBarContainer` -> `ActionBarView` -> `AbsActionBarView` -> `ViewGroup`

Idea:

Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/NikolaDespotoski/6978883) and see how menu items are accessed and referenced as `View`

Next:

1. Hide all menu item but get their icon resource or entire `View` you see in the gist.
2. Use `ObjectAnimator` or `ViewPropertyAnimator` to animate the `x`for going in and out.
3. Once the animation has ended, change the visibilty of the menus

Note that this is dirty way. It can be slow due to the reflection.

Comment: It's always the dirty way with Android :) I'll try to reproduce it, thank you.

Comment: It's possible, you have to follow that code until you get the MenuItem holder with (LinearLayout)actionMenuViewField.get(actionMenuPresenter);